# Class not found, namespace, subfolder

Tags: php, class, namespaces, phalcon, autoloader

I have cli app with a couple of classes which resides in */core/modules*. Too much, so I want some of them to be in */core/modules/evaluate/* with Class *Core\Modules\Evaluate\Something*. On my local computer this works, but not on a remote server.

Init in *public/index.php*:

```
// Init loader
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
// Register applications necessary directories
$loader->registerDirs(
    [
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/tasks',
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/backend',
```

...

```
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/risk'
    ]
)->registerNamespaces( // Additionally, register core namespace
        [
            'Core\Helper' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/core/helper',
            'Core\Interfaces' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/core/interfaces',
            'Core\Modules' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/core/modules',
            'Core\Modules\Evaluate' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/core/modules/evaluate',
            'Rest' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/rest'
        ]
    );
```

And this is the head of one of the modules in *core/modules/evaluate:*

```
<?php
namespace Core\Modules\Evaluate;
use Core\Modules;
class Evaluatewin extends Modules\EvaluateBet {
```

Any hints?

Comment: Where do you `require_once` the class file?

Comment: Does i have to `require_once` the class file because it is in a subfolder? I thought it is done by the autoloader.

Comment: Autoloading is probably not working properly.. Can you try to require_once the file explicitely?

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

Did you finally call -

$loader->register();

Comment: So is the class file even inside a subfolder in the evaluate directory ?
And also could you print the exact error like whether it was a class not found exception, etc.